# How to write bean to CSV using OpenCSV without converting to String[]?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have a large array of a bean that needs to be written to a CSV file. I am trying to use OpenCSV but all the examples I see on the web ask me to convert the bean (POJO) that I have to a string array. I don't want to do this since this would mean I will have to go through the million beans and convert each of those beans to String[] which would be a very memory-expensive process.

This is the piece of code I have right now for doing this:

```
private static void writeRowsToCsv(Path filePath, List<MyBean> rows)
        throws IOException {

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer, '#', '\'');
    ColumnPositionMappingStrategy mappingStrategy =
            new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
    mappingStrategy.setType(MyBean.class);
    List<String[]> rowsInStringArray = convertBeanToStringArray(rows)
    csvWriter.writeAll(rowsInStringArray);
}
```

Is there a way I can avoid the conversion to `String[]` and use the list of beans that I have to write to a CSV file?

Comment: Why would that be very memory-expensive? You call `writeNext()` in a loop, converting one bean at a time.

Comment: That would mean I am writing one row at a time. I have a millions of rows to be written, which would make it extremely slow.

Comment: What do you think `writeAll()` does? It iterates the list and writes them, one at a time. How else would it process the list?

Comment: I haven't investigated but I believe it writes a batch of rows at a time.

Comment: What batching? There is no batching. Stop trying to guess when you have no clue. `writeAll()` is nothing but a loop calling `writeNext()`. See [source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.java#l178).

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. That means the best way out here is to call `writeNext()` in a loop. If you can write that out as an answer, I could mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `writeNext()` in a loop, converting one bean at a time. Not memory-expensive at all.

Answer (score 8):

Jobin, seriously, if you are using OpenCSV then use the `BeanToCsv` or the newer `StatefulBeanToCsv`. It will save your sanity.

```
private static void writeRowsToCsv(Path filePath, List<MyBean> rows)
        throws IOException {

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    ColumnPositionMappingStrategy mappingStrategy =
            new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
    mappingStrategy.setType(MyBean.class);

    StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<MyBean> builder = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer);
    StatefulBeanToCsv beanWriter = builder
              .withMappingStrategy(mappingStrategy)
              .withSeparator('#')
              .withQuotechar('\'')
              .build();

    beanWriter.write(rows);
}
```

Comment: The constructor StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(CSVWriter) does not exist.

Comment: ledlogic - you are absolutely correct.  I corrected my code example above as the StatefulBeanToCsv creates a CSVWriter based on values passed in from the builder but it does not take a CSVWriter directly.   Not exactly sure what I was thinking back in May but thank you for pointing that out because who knows how long that would have stayed there.

Comment: this is the easier way to do it.

Comment: In OpenCSV 5.7.0, there is a constructor StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(ICSVWriter) and CSVWriter implements it via AbstractCSVWriter.